# Avoid decimal points in X-axis in Google charts

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, decimal

I am using **Google chart**, and I create a **horizondal stacked chart**. My array for drawing chart is

```
[['name','count',{ role: "style" }],
['abc', 1, '#4CAF50'],
['pqr', 2, '#4CAF50'],
['xyz', 1, '#4CAF50'],
['efg', 1, '#4CAF50'],
['klm', 2, '#4CAF50']]
```

This resulting the `X-axis` points `0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0.`

But I `want to avoid the decimal points in X-axis.`

For this I tried:

```
hAxis: {
          format: '#'
        }
```

AND

```
hAxis: {
          format: '0'
        }
```

But these gives the `X-axis` as: `1, 1, 2, 2.` *This is not desirable.*

I want the the `X-axis` points something like: `1, 2, 3, 4`

How can I do this? Any help is really appreciable...

Comment: are you looking for histogram:http ?://jsfiddle.net/suchit/q44jryg3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could specify X-axis explicitly via `ticks` option. But since your goal is set ticks based on the input data, you could specify it as demonstrated below:

```js
google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Year', 'Sold Books (M)', { role: 'annotation' }],
        ['2010', 1.1, ''],
        ['2011', 3.0, ''],
        ['2012', 9.0, ''],
        ['2013', 7.3, ''],
        ['2014', 3.5, '']
    ]);




    var options = {
        width: 600,
        height: 400,
        legend: { position: "none" },
        isStacked: true,
        hAxis: {
            ticks: calcIntTicks(data,1)
        }
    };
    var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById("barchart_values"));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}

function calcIntTicks(dataTable,step) {
    var min = Math.floor(dataTable.getColumnRange(1).min);
    var max = Math.ceil(dataTable.getColumnRange(1).max);
    var vals = [];
    for (var cur = min; cur <= max; cur+=step) {
        vals.push(cur);
    }
    return vals;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<div id="barchart_values" style="width: 900px; height: 300px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the ticks option. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/ramanbedi1989/h4r8pps6/) is the fiddle for it.

```
ticks: [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: this is good, but I can't specify the axis points because it is generate dynamically. However +1 for your answer(it is really new to me), and I am sure this will help me later works..

Comment: You can generate the array using the output from your dynamic data and input that array to the ticks parameter. By this way you'll be able to define the interval of your choice.

Comment: NO..the X-axis values and the X-axis points may not be same. If I get the array values [1,3, 9, 3, 6, 7, 3] then the X-axis points should be 1 to 9 or 10 OR [2, 4, 8, 10]  OR whatever it is (not contain decimal that is the only condition). I think you got the point..

Comment: As such, you would take your array values, convert to whole numbers, sort, remove duplicates, etc...